# x64 processor module

Tags: x86-64

I just downloaded Ghidra last evening on a Fedora Linux machine with 4 Intel Core i5-7200U CPUs.
When querying the "installed processor modules" in "Help" I get a listing of 41 processors.
x86 is on the list, but x64 is not.
How do I fix that, and get the x64 processor module installed?

Comment: Ah ... maybe x86 includes x86-64?

Answer (score 2):

It's called `x86` but you have the option to pick size - 64.
 [image]

Comment: Thanks !  I had read the IDA documentation first, in which x86 and x64 were completely different products for which you had to buy separately.

Comment: It's helpful to note that to change the processor language, right-click on the prorgam file (which is not at all obvious).  This cannot be undone, so be careful.  This really should not be necessary as the default gets automatically picked based on the content of the binary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's automatic.  I don't have to pick size.

When I create a new project with a 64 bit binary the project shows:

Processor=x86, Endian=little, Address Size=64, Compiler=gcc, Format=ELF

When I create a new project with a 32 bit binary the project shows:

Processor=x86, Endian=little, Addesss Size=32, Compiler=gcc, Format=ELF